# IBM Db2: select numeric characters only from a column

Tags: sql, regex, db2, ibm-cloud

I have a column 'TEST_COLUMN' that carries 3 values:

```
123
123ad(44)
w-eq1dfd2
```

I need to SELECT TEST_COLUMN but get the following result:

```
123
12344
12
```

I am running on Db2 Warehouse on Cloud.

Comment: which version and platform?

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE something?

Comment: IBM Db2 Warehouse on Cloud,Type:Enterprise Plan - Single Node

Comment: see answer below - please mark as answered if that fits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
   '123Red345', '[A-Za-z]','',1) 
      FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The query would return "123345".

Because you asked below, here is the generic version:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(YOUR_COLUMN, '[A-Za-z]','',1) 
          FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
```

Comment: how do I get it to remove  -   as well ?

Comment: I added the answer to address your question regarding column and schema

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your NEW question

Comment: thank you so much sir. I figured out the table and schema thing. I'm so stupid for asking that question. as for the second question : i mean special characters like "-" ... dashes and others

Comment: You would need to add to the regex pattern. See the docs for your options, the link is included.