# How to remove "-" from a column in DB2 table

Tags: replace, db2

If Phone has "918-435-0000" and want to remove"-" result should be - 9184350000, I can use substring with position 4 and 8? or shall I be using replace function ?

here in my example are special characters like - or sometimes +1(505) 000-2798

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151437/ibm-db2-select-numeric-characters-only-from-a-column/56151536#56151536 Use the dashes as characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBM Db2: select numeric characters only from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151437/ibm-db2-select-numeric-characters-only-from-a-column)

Comment: I am trying - REGEXP_LIKE(phone1,'[^\d]') to get the list of phone numbers which are having - or (,) in them, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details on your attempts instead of statements like just `its not working`.
Does the following work for you?

```
with t(phone1) as (values
  '+1(505) 000-2798'
, '918-435-0000'
, '9184350000'
)
select phone1, REGEXP_REPLACE(phone1, '[^\d]', '') phone1_replaced
from t
where REGEXP_LIKE(phone1, '[^\d]');
```